# show and hide all sections with dropdown select options it ones in elementor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, elementor

I have a dropdown list
below it, I have 9 section

1.section id=Hige x 3

2.section id=Medium x 3

3.section id=Low x 3

I tend to do - when I select Hige, all sections with Hige will be shown. when I choose Medium only all sections of Medium will be shown. And so on. I use jQuery for this
**The problem is** that it only shows one section, Hige or Medium or Low

Thanks for all the answers and helpers really thank you very much

the code I write is:

```
<select id="test" >
    <option value="High">High room</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium room</option>
    <option value="Low">low room</option>
 </select>


.content{
    display: none;
}
#High{
    display: block;
}
 jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('#test').change(function(){
      jQuery('.content').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.content').hide();
  $('#test').change(function() {
    //console.log($(this).val())
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

#High {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="High">High room</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium room</option>
  <option value="Low">low room</option>
</select>
<div class="content High">
  High
</div>
<div class="content High">
  High
</div>

<div class="content Medium">
  Medium
</div>
<div class="content Medium">
  Medium
</div>

<div class="content Low">
  Low
</div>
<div class="content Low">
  Low
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: can you clarify what you'er after, your question says to "when I choose Medium only all sections of Medium will be shown" so you would have to hide the other sections !? I updated the above example to keep the selection that is picked always showing is that what you wanted ?

Comment: is that because you using id, if you reference a class they should all hide/show, I still don't fully understand the first example I gave you did what you were asking for as it hid all the other elements and showed those with the name in the selected option !??

Comment: yes so then use the class name like so: jQuery('.' + jQuery(this).val()).show(); that will show all elements with the class name matching the selected value  !?

Comment: that's ok, I'm sorry I'm not fully understanding what you're after, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/95ouyjp6/2/  see how that shows all the divs with the class name that matches the dropdown select if that doesn't work on your site then its an issue  with Elementor, it that's not what you want or isn't the issue you having to change it and post the jsfiddle link

Comment: @MosheDvir  you are using id as a selector (`#`) right?

Comment: as you said it works here but not on Elementor , then that suggests it is an issue with  Elementor, perhaps you should contact them and seek advise

Comment: I understood what the problem was: the function calls only one class. In jquery, there is a command that calls all classes along with the same name. The problem was that I could not figure out how to perform the function.In the meantime the only and long way I have found looks like this <div class="Settings"> 
<select id="test">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="High, High" >High </option>
    <option value="Medium, Medium">Medium </option>
    <option value="Low, Low">low</option>
 </select>
 </div>

Comment: If anyone has a shorter way I would love to hear

Comment: when you say the function what do you mean ? are you talking about vanilla js, i jquery you just use $('.MyCLassNameOnEliments') as in the demo, sounds like your issue int with jquery but something else entirly